# Symfony2 CLI Error ( 'stty' is not recognized as an internal or external command )

Tags: php, symfony, entity, stty

I get the following error when trying to generate an entity in Symfony2 from the Windows command line:

```
'stty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i'v just added FOSUserBundle to my Symfony Bundles. and tried to make an entity.

the error appears elsewhere too.

I also added FOSUserBundle User Management.
OS: Windows 7
xampp package for PHP.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has something to do with this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4974).